# Constructor list initialization of an empty vector

Tags: c++, vector

Which is the appropriate way (if any) to list initialize an empty vector on the class ctor assuming?:

```
class Temp {
    private:
        int vals;
        vector<int> A;
    public:
        Temp(int x);
};
```

All of these seem to work, but is it even necessary to do #1 or #2, or is declaration enough?:

**1: Calling vector constructor explicitly**

`Temp::Temp(int x):vals(x), A() { }`

**2: Using vector list initialization within class ctor list initialization**

`Temp::Temp(int x):vals(x), A{} { }`

**3: Excluding from class ctor list initialization (declaration only)**

`Temp::Temp(int x):vals(x) { }`

There doesnt appear to be any value from including the vector member in the class ctor initialization list since its default constructor is called when we declare it and returns an empty vector.

Comment: For `std::vector`, there is no difference between *default-initialization* and *value-initialization* -- both call the zero argument constructor.  For primitive types and aggregates containing primitive types, they are different.

Comment: `A{}` calls the default class constructor, it's not a list initialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which is the appropriate way (if any) to list initialize an empty vector on the class ctor assuming?

They are all valid.

It is mostly a matter of style. If you do care about setting all class members in the constructor member initializer list explicitly, then you might include initialization of `A` for consistency, otherwise, `std::vector` default constructor is called automatically.

Usually, only the members which require some kind of non-default initialization go to the [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

> Before the compound statement that forms the function body of the
>   constructor begins executing, initialization of all direct bases,
>   virtual bases, and non-static data members is finished. *Member
>   initializer list is the place where non-default initialization of
>   these objects can be specified.* For members that cannot be
>   default-initialized, such as members of reference and const-qualified
>   types, member initializers must be specified. No initialization is
>   performed for anonymous unions or variant members that do not have a
>   member initializer.